# Sitecore Spell checker neglect search scope

Tags: sxa, solr, content-search

I'm using Sitecore 9.1 and SXA 1.8, I'm using Solr spell checker feature to fetch suggestions for a SXA search box that I use, the source of the suggestions is the field you specify in the **SpellCheckComponent** configurations,let's say I specify the **Title** field,I assign a search scope for the Search box component which get all the News items in my site, the search box suggestions supposed to be from News items only, but this is not the case as the suggestions are from any item that has the field **Title**.

Comment: I think we'll need a bit more info and details to provide an answer..

Comment: @Gatogordo I edited the question adding more details

Comment: I think by more details @Gatogordo meant the steps you took to configure the spell checker and all the other steps so that someone could reasonably follow to reproduce your setup.

Comment: SpellCheckComponent is related to whole index. I mean that if you index has field=Title not only for `News` then you will see all these titles. If you need to see only titles for `News`, you should 1) store only news in index or 2) create custom computed field for spell checker and store only titles for your new (skip the rest of title from indexing in this field).

Comment: @x3mxray Thank you so much for your help, it's clear now.